# Fullscreen Chrome without user action

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

I have a computer connected to a TV that I'm using only as an activity monitoring screen. I want it to be showing a website fullscreen in Chrome.

Due to security reasons it's not allowed to force any user to go into fullscreen mode without user action. However I'm looking for a work-around that enables me to go into fullscreen on page load.

Is there any setting I can change in my Chrome browser to work around this, and allow my browser to go to fullscreen on page load?

The only other solution I thought of so far would be to install some sort of auto-clicker for my OS that clicks a fullscreen button for me, but that feels kind of silly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is two options to archive fullscreen without user interaction:

**Chrome `--start-fullscreen` flag**

This can make any website fullscreen but you need access to the computer you want to open the website on.

You can use the flag in command line: `chrome --start-fullscreen http://localhost` or with a Chrome desktop shortcut.

To add a desktop shortcut in Chrome, go in the `Main menu > More tools > Create shortcut...`

After that, you should have a shortcut on you desktop. Right click on it, go on Properties, and add the flag in: Target on Windows or Command on Ubuntu.

**Progressive Web Application**

To make a [PWA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Progressive/Installable_PWAs) your web app needs to [meet the minimum requirements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Progressive/Installable_PWAs#Requirements).